Custom pulse with fake backend not running for Cross Resonance Pulse
I am trying to create a cross resonance pulse by driving the control qubit at a non resonant frequency. My code runs but does not stop running.
#Creating pulse
with pulse.build(backend) as cr_pulse:
    pulse.shift_frequency(freq_offresonant, controlchannel_0)

    pulse.play(GaussianSquare(duration=num_samples, amp=amp, sigma=16, width=width), controlchannel_0)

cr_pulse.draw()

#Create circuit
circ_cr = QuantumCircuit(2)
passmanager = generate_preset_pass_manager(optimization_level=1, backend=backend)

circ_cr.cx(0,1)

circ_cr.add_calibration('cr pulse', [0, 1], cr_pulse)

circ_cr.draw("mpl")

#Transpile
circ_cr_transpile = transpile(circ_cr, backend)
circ_cr_transpile.draw("mpl")

#Run
# Set up the QPT experiment
qpt_cr = ProcessTomography(circ_cr_transpile)

#Run
qstdata_cr = qpt_cr.run(backend=FakeValenciaV2, seed_simulation=100, shots=shots).block_for_results()

#Results 
for result in qstdata_cr.analysis_results():
    print(result)

Does anyone know what the problem is?
There seems to be an issue with the transpiler:
pass_manager = generate_preset_pass_manager(3, backend)
transpile_circ = transpile(circ_cr, backend=backend)

where I get one of two errors:
TranspilerError: "HighLevelSynthesis was unable to synthesize Instruction(name='cr_pulse', num_qubits=2, num_clbits=0, params=[])."

or:
TranspilerError: 'Only a single input coupling map can be used with transpile() if you need to target different coupling maps for different circuits you must call transpile() multiple times'

